# Char count in string

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and FP in general and trying to practice it on a dummy example.

```
val counts = ransomNote.map(e=>(e,1)).reduceByKey{case (x,y) => x+y}
```

The following error is raised:

```
Line 5: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)] (in solution.scala)
```

The above example looks similar to staring FP primer on word count, I'll appreciate it if you point on my mistake.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example and expected result?

Comment: Can you accept one of below answer or explain what extra you expect ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a Spark method on a Scala collection. The two APIs have a few similarities, but `reduceByKey` is not part of it.

In pure Scala you can do it like this:

```
val counts =
  ransomNote.foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int].withDefaultValue(0)) {
    (counts, c) => counts.updated(c, counts(c) + 1)
  }
```

`foldLeft` iterates over the collection from the left, using the empty map of counts as the accumulated state (which returns 0 is no value is found), which is updated in the function passed as argument by being updated with the found value, incremented.

Note that accessing a map directly (`counts(c)`) is likely to be unsafe in most situations (since it will throw an exception if no item is found). In this situation it's fine because in this scope I know I'm using a map with a default value. When accessing a map you will more often than not want to use `get`, which returns an `Option`. More on that on the official Scala documentation ([here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.2/scala/collection/Map.html#get(key:K):Option[V]) for version 2.13.2).

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/zOcmFAujSyiMtly49KlChg/3).

Answer (score 4):

On **Scala 2.13** you can use the new `groupMapReduce`

```
ransomNote.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val str = "hello"
val countsMap: Map[Char, Int] = str
  .groupBy(identity)
  .mapValues(_.length)

println(countsMap)
```